# video sequence editor seconds milliseconds

Tags: video-sequence-editor, units

Is there a way to see the units in seconds+ milliseconds rather than seconds + frame in video sequence editor? I am trying to sync dialogues from a track in audacity and every time I have to do the math of converting seconds to frames.

Comment: Why not let Audacity display the frames to match those in Blender? You can adjust the view down there in Audacity...

Comment: yeah, that's what I ended up doing. Thanks!